# VB.Net/Serial-Port: How to determine unique string convention to communicate with serial port device?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

Need to send string information to a serial device on COM1 - if it works, I will see evidence on a separate internet application. If I understand correctly, there is a necessary string format to use to communicate with the device, but I don't know what it is. I assume this is because there are multiple values being sent to the device in a single transaction. How can I determine the proper format, or can I force a response from the device to tell me?

I've tested my full code using virtual COM ports and saw success with the code sending data. Testing with the actual device showed no success on the separate internet app. The code below is the receiving end - no results from it.

```
    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As 
        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

    End Sub



    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)

        If Me.TB_OUTPUT.InvokeRequired Then

            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})

        Else

            Me.TB_OUTPUT.Text &= [text]

        End If

    End Sub
```

Neither the virtual testing, nor the device testing garnered any response back through the sending COM port as I had expected. Breaking code and checking variables showed no results either. I assume this is all because I am not sending data in a proper format...?

Comment: If information such as the specification of the target device or communication protocol is not added to the question contents, no answer or advice will be obtained.

Comment: You should look at the documentation for the device, you should be able to obtain it from the manufacturer. Some manufactureres decide to implement their own protocols while others follow conventions such as Modbus RTU. There is not really an easy way for you to determine what it is by yourself.

Comment: You have both answered my question. Does not seem possible to determine it myself without knowing what protocol the manufacturer uses, which I don't believe is available to me. However I did learn something here, so Thank you!